# SCALA multiple nested case statement in map RDD operations

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, case

I have an RDD with 7 string elements 
linesData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, String, String, String, String)] 
I need to figure out for each record the following 2 items:  Status and CSrange.

the logic is something like:

```
case when a(6)=0 
    if Date(a(5)) > Date(a(4)) then
        if Date(a(5)) - Date(a(4)) > 60 days then
            staus = '60+'
        else 
            status = 'Curr'
        endif
    else
        status = 'Curr'
    end
when (a(6) >=1 and a(6) <=3 ) then
        Status = 'In-Forcl'
when (a(6) >=4 and a(6) <=8)
    Status = 'Forclosed'
else 
    Status = 'Unknown' 
end case


case  when  (a(1) <640 and a(1) >0 ) then CSrange = '<640'
      when (a(1) <650 and a(1)> 579 then CSrange = '640-649'
      when (a(1) <660 and a(1)> 619 then CSrange = '650-659'
      when (a(1) <680 and a(1)> 639 then CSrange = '640-649'
      when (a(1) >789 then CSrange = '680+'
else    
      CSRange ='Unknown'
end case
```

At this point, I would like to write the data out to disk, with probably 9 elements insteatd of 7. (later I will need to do calculate the rate of each of the statuses above by various elements).

My first problems are:
1. how to do date arithmetics?  as I need to stay at the RDD level (no data frames). 
2. I don't know how to do the CASE statements in SCALA.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
(2017_7_0555,794,Scott,CORNERSTONE,8/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_0557,682,Hennepin,LAKE AREA MT,9/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_0565,754,Ramsey,GUARANTEED R,6/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_0570,645,Hennepin,FAIRWAY INDE,2/1/2015,8/1/2017,5)
(2017_7_0574,732,Wright,GUARANTEED R,7/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_0575,789,Hennepin,GUARANTEED R,8/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_0577,662,Hennepin,MIDCOUNTRY,8/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_4550,642,Mower,WELLS FARGO,5/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_4574,689,Hennepin,RIVER CITY,8/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_4584,662,Hennepin,WELLS FARGO,8/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
(2017_7_4600,719,Ramsey,PHH HOME LOA,5/1/2017,8/1/2017,0)
```

Comment: Because some of it is for school project.

Comment: is your data line delimited or not ? can you format input data correctly ?

Comment: Yes.  Input is clean.

Comment: I have edited your question. please check  if the formatting is correct for input data. is the data with the brackets?

Comment: the source data are clean csv files.  (no extra commas), with about 40 fields per line.  the rdd in the sample data is generated by splitting the on ","  and extracting 7 fields (field 0, is actually concatenating 3 fields).  giving me the rdd with array of 7 strings linesData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, String, String, String, String)]   and the sample data was by linesData.take(11).foreach(println).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a case class of seven fields and map RDD[(*,*...)] to RDD[MyClass] and cast to appropriate types. I recommend you [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) date library for dates. This will make your code more descriptive.

Then in a map extract status and range into two functions:

```
myRDD.map(myInstance => (getStatus(myInstance), getRange(myInstance)))

def getStatus(myInstance: MyClass) : String = {
    val (_,_,_,_,date4,date5,field6,_) = MyClass.unapply(myInstance).get
    field6 match {
        case 0 => {
            if(date5.isAfter(date4) {
               if(date4.plusDays(60).isAfter(date5)){
                   "60+"
               } else {
                   "Curr"
               }
            }
        }
        case x if (x >= 1 && x <= 3) => "Forclosed"
        ....
    } 
}
```

Note:

- I haven't tested the code.
- Rename variables from the example.
- I show you an example about how to manage JodaTime dates, and scala pattern matching. You have to finish the function and define the other one.

Comment: I am new to Scala,.. can I use the class in a spark-shell code? how? and can I/how to import JodaTime library to spark-shell?

Comment: You don't need to work in spark-shell. You can use an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij, it will help you.   If you are using spark-shell you can add --jars <your_jar> option to import libraríes.